# Android Java constructor creating and holding other type objects and be able to reference that data

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, constructor

So I make class to control many other objects of the same type but when I reference that object to get to a data structure I keep getting null but if I the secondary object is static it works. I'm not sure why though?  I made the main object static. Hopefully the code makes more sense. Instantiate a  new Gameboard and made it static then the GameBoard constructor makes 6 new SurfaceFaces and in each surface a constructor that makes arrayList with data in it. I'm trying to get to that specific array inside of that SurfaceFace object. If there's a better way logical or programmatically open to any suggestions? The call I'm making that i'm getting a null is `MainActivity.board.getSurface("SideA").getList()`

MainActivity.class

```
    static GameBoard board;

    MainActivity()
    {

     onCreate()
    {
     GameBoard board = new GameBoard();
    }
    }
```

GameBoard.class

```
public class GameBoard {

    SurfaceFace SideA ; 
    SurfaceFace SideB ;
    SurfaceFace SideC ;
    SurfaceFace SideD ;
    SurfaceFace SideE ;
    SurfaceFace SideF ;

    GameBoard()
    {
        SurfaceFace SideA = new SurfaceFace();
        SurfaceFace SideB = new SurfaceFace();
        SurfaceFace SideC = new SurfaceFace();
        SurfaceFace SideD = new SurfaceFace();
        SurfaceFace SideE = new SurfaceFace();
        SurfaceFace SideF = new SurfaceFace();

    }

    public SurfaceFace getSurface(String name)
    {
        if (name.equals("SideA"))
                {
                    return SideA;
                }
        if (name.equals("SideB"))
        {
            return SideB;
        }
        return SideA;

    }


}
```

SurfaceFace.class

```
public class SurfaceFace {

    ArrayList<Item> SurfaceSide = new ArrayList<Item>(AppConstant.grid_size);


    SurfaceFace()
    {

        initArray();
    }

    private void initArray() 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < AppConstant.grid_size; i++) 
        {
            SurfaceSide.add(new Item("Initial", i, "yellow"));

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getList()
    {
        return SurfaceSide;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your main constructor doesn't instantiate the class level variable. `class Main { GameBoard board; public Main() { board = new GameBoard(); }}`

Comment: maybe I should change this question b/c of it being in android?

Comment: Objects must start with uppercase, variables with lowercase.

Comment: I think your right about board = new GameBoard(); and I also change inside of the constructor sideA = new Surface();.  This works now. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring variables within the constructor that hide your class level variables. What you need to do is just the assignments  -

```
GameBoard() {
    SideA = new SurfaceFace(); // remove class name at the beginning
    SideB = new SurfaceFace();
    SideC = new SurfaceFace();
    SideD = new SurfaceFace();
    SideE = new SurfaceFace();
    SideF = new SurfaceFace();
}
```